# What duty fees can I expect to take a new bike into Bangladesh?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, local-customs

Can I buy a bike in India while I am travelling here, and take it back to Bangladesh?

If yes, then how much will be the duty charges for a bike? (Price ₹60000-70000)

Answer (score 1):

There's a tax and duty calculator at [Customs Duty Free](https://customsdutyfree.com/duty-calculator/) that will give you an estimate of the taxes and duties payable. I've reproduced below the calculation for importing a bicycle valued at 70,000 taka (about INR63,000), no insurance, no shipping.

The total taxes and duties payable on import are approximately 39,000 taka.

You should perform your own calculation based on actual values, and be aware that this site may not be authoritative.

---

CUSTOMSDUTYFREE.COM

One stop shop for customs duty for 100+ countries

The Customs duty calculation for Bicycle is as follows:

Country Details :

From Country : India

To Country : Bangladesh

---

Product details :

Product description : Bicycle

Category : Sports & Outdoors

Sub Category : Bicycle

Item name : Bicycle With Both Wheels Size > 63.5cm

Hs code : 87-12-0-0-0

---

**Extra taxes details :**

**REGULATORY DUTY IS : 4375**

**ADVANCE INCOME TAX IS : 4375**

Supplementary duty of 0 to 437500 applicable on certain products

---

Calculation details :

Item cost : 70000

Shipment cost : 0

Insurance cost : 0

CIF value (item cost + shipment cost + insurance cost) : 70000

Customs duty rate : 25%

CUSTOMS DUTY (customs duty rate * (CIF)) : 17500

Vat rate : 15%

VAT (vat rate * (Customs duty+CIF+other taxes if applicable)) : 13781.25

**Total amount to be paid : 110031.25**(excluding extra taxes if applicable)

The above duty has been calculated from 'https://customsdutyfree.com' on 2018-11-03.

Note: All the rates and values are shown in respective country currency.

Copyright © customsdutyfree.com 2017