# Importing a bike from India to Bangladesh

Tags: customs-and-immigration, international-travel, india, import-taxes, bangladesh

Is it possible to buy a brand new bike from India and bring into Bangladesh? 
If it is possible, how much are the custom charges likely to be?

Comment: Is there a travel aspect to this? If not, this is likely to be closed as off-topic.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass Cycling from India to Bangladesh with border crossing formality sounds like a travel issue.

Comment: @gerrit If that is indeed what the OP is doing. As written, he's asking about importing a new bike into Bangladesh. There's no indication that he, or anyone, is riding it, or even travelling with it.

Answer (score -1):

I think this [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/125073/what-duty-fees-can-i-expect-to-take-a-new-bike-into-bangladesh?answertab=oldest#tab-top) will fulfill your query. You can check. And check this Bangladesh govt [tariff schedule](http://www.bsbk.gov.bd/site/page/dc19d583-9315-4885-ba0b-f21de9ee3c52/%E0%A6%AC%E0%A7%87%E0%A6%A8%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%AA%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%B2-%E0%A6%B8%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%A5%E0%A6%B2%E0%A6%AC%E0%A6%A8%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%A6%E0%A6%B0). And this [post](https://bikeguybd.com/1179/). It will help you understand.

Comment: As it stands this answer relies on links. If those links go dead it will lose its point. Can you summarise the content of the external links by editing please?

Comment: My first link is almost fulfill his query and it is on travel.exchange.com site and second link is government official site, so can't go down.

Comment: Questions do get deleted and for many reasons. So a link inside Travel Stack Exchange is not as safe as you imply. Governmental sites do change and change URL's, and they do sometimes go down under attacks. So please quote the most important parts of those links, but keep the link as well for the full information (as long as it is still available.) And your last link was in a different language from English, you should give a short translation of the relevant parts so people can understand without having to use a translating service.